# Win10 System clock at local time, but display UTC in taskbar (or widget?)

Tags: windows-10, clock

I don't want to change my system's time to UTC (so all my file operations and email dates and such are local), but I want to view UTC as my primary clock on the bottom right of the taskbar.  Is this possible?

I know I can add an additional clock via settings, but it's only visible if I open the calendar.  Also, I know I can pin clocks to the start menu via alarms and clocks app, but that's too out of the way as well.

Alternatively, if I can't update the main taskbar clock like this, is there a widget of some sort so I can embed a clock into the desktop? (I'm trying to force myself to use UTC to become fluent in it...)